# Check local storage variable already present, if not create a new one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I want to create local storage variable by checking it already present or not. If variable already exist change the variable name and create a new one. But i could not understand how to do it. Please help me with this. Thanks

Here is my code

```
var vCount=1;
var vName='SESSION_'+vCount;
while(localStorage.getItem(vName) === null)
{

   vCount++;
   vName='SESSION_'+vCount;

   //if variable name available create a new variable 
}
```

Comment: What is the break condition here? When do you want to stop creating new localStorage variable?

Comment: Here is my problem, it causes infinite loop. Maybe I have done wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Start with the count to get the name and then query local storage to see if it exists. If so - increment the count and save that value to the loan storage. If not - it doesn't exist so save the original.

```
var vCount=1;
var vName='SESSION_'+vCount;

var storedName= sessionStorage.getItem("vName");
if (storedName){
    var vCount += 1;
    var vName='SESSION_' + vCount;
    localStorage.setItem(vName, vName);
    //this will increment the number and set that as the variable name
} else {
  localStorage.setItem("vName", vName);
}
```

Comment: have to increment vCount. I want varible name like SESSION_1, SESSION_2 respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:
(I am considering you just want to create one new local variable)

```
var vCount=1;
var vName='SESSION_'+vCount;
while(true && localStorage)
{
   //if variable name not available create a new variable 
   if(!localStorage.getItem(vName)){
     localStorage.setItem(vName,"your value");
     break;
   }
   vCount++;
   vName='SESSION_'+vCount;
}
```

Comment: localStorage is just to check whether your current browser supports localStorage or not (useful in old browsers like IE 7,8).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using recursion :

```
var vCount=1;
function storeVariable(valueToStore){    
    var vName='SESSION_'+vCount;
    if(localStorage.getItem(vName) === null){
        vCount++;
        vName='SESSION_'+vCount;

        //if variable name available create a new variable 
    }else{
        storeVariable(valueToStore);
    }
}

//you can reset vCount = 1 before calling this function, if you need to start the counter over again.
storeVariable(valueToStore);
```